# Eclipse taking lot of time to build Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I see that Eclipse takes hell lot of time to build project. Is there any way to fasten the build process?

Comment: Running your app on device or emulator?

Comment: Both on device and emulator.. Got a solution ...

Comment: Fine. Thanks for sharing here. Don't forget to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guys found the solution,
There is a tool developed by Chainfire..
[FAAPT](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1907281)
Download the zip, Replace the aapt file in your platform tools by this one.. Its super fast.. i can build the project in just 2 -3 seconds.. :)

Comment: superfast solution. just in 2 minutes. :o